# how to find number of elements in an array of strings in c++?

Tags: c++

i have an array of string.

**std::string str[10] = {"one","two"}**

How to find how many strings are present inside the `str[]` array?? Is there any standard function?

Comment: Do you mean non-null, non-empty strings?     No.

Comment: ya u can say that...as there are right know only 2 strings present.

Comment: You can find it at runtime. see my answer below. I wonder if it can happen at compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to count all elements `sizeof` technique will work as others pointed out.
If you want to count all non-empty strings, this is one possible way by using the standard `count_if` function.

```
bool IsNotEmpty( const std::string& str )
{
    return !str.empty();
}


int main ()
{
    std::string str[10] = {"one","two"};

    int result = std::count_if(str, &str[10], IsNotEmpty);
    cout << result << endl; // it will print "2"

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @baash05: you could use `find_if(..., IsEmpty)` if you *knew* the first empty element delimited the in-use values.

Answer (score 7):

There are *ten* strings in there despite the fact that you have only initialised two of them:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    std::string str[10] = {"one","two"};
    std::cout << sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str) << std::endl;
    std::cout << str[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << str[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << str[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "===" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
10
one
two

===
```

If you want to count the non-empty strings:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    std::string str[10] = {"one","two"};
    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str); i++)
        if (str[i] != "")
            count++;
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `2` as expected.

Comment: Ya thats true. but when i run a loop then how can i come to know that i need to loop it twice only?

Comment: You'd compare the element to the `null` string and thats when yous stop your loop

Comment: Don't run it twice only. Run it 10 times and skip those where the underlying string is empty.

Comment: Sorry mate.  
Three issues. 1.  Why keep figuring out how many elements in the string
Second.. What if there are 10,000,000  Order N.  Really
Last why not return size_t.  You code could easily overrun. the count should be the same type as the for-iterator.

Comment: @baash05: (1) You can manually cache that if you like but, unless your compiler is totally brain-dead, it will already be doing that. (2) Doesn't matter. Unless you're _certain_ all the empty strings are at the end, you have to look at every index. You can binary search if you know that fact but I'd probably just have a different class that maintained the count and adjusted it in a setter (changing non-null to null -> `count--`, null to non-null -> `count++`). (3) Yes, missed that, will change. But, if you have that many strings, you've got more problems than integer overflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that I would use an array of std::strings. If you're already using the STL, why not consider a vector or list? At least that way you could just figure it out with std::vector::size() instead of working ugly sizeof magic. Also, that sizeof magic won't work if the array is stored on the heap rather than the stack.

Just do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings(10);
strings[0] = "one";
strings[1] = "two";

std::cout << "Length = " << strings.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: But the question is for finding the active strings in array. However `vector<>` would be a good idea for finding size, very straight forward.

Comment: Ah shoot gotta start reading the entire question + comments. He could always use a vector, push_back the vector with strings, and then just do vector.size(). I don't see why he would ever have inactive strings as long as he pop_back's

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `countof` macro to get the number of elements, but again, the memory was allocated for 10 elements and thats the count that you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this is

```
std::string str[] = {"one","two"}

int num_of_elements = sizeof( str ) / sizeof( str[ 0 ] );
```

Comment: He defined the size of the array in the constructor. 
So while your code here would work.  str[10] (as per his code) would have 10 strings.  All be-it some would be empty.

Comment: That's what I meant. You don't need to supply array length all the time

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the size. 
You could do a binary search for not null/empty.

str[9] is empty
str[5] is empty
str[3] is not empty
str[4] is empty  
You have 4 items.

I don't really feel like implementing the code, but this would be quite quick.

Comment: It wouldn't work if there are empty strings in the middle of the array. We could use this if we have our own insert so we can keep the array sorted. I wouldn't do this until it becomes a real bottle-neck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function for 1D string array:

```
template<typename String, uint SIZE>  // String can be 'string' or 'const string'
unsigned int NoOfStrings (String (&arr)[SIZE])
{
  unsigned int count = 0;
  while(count < SIZE && arr[count] != "")
    count ++;
  return count;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::string s1 = {"abc", "def" };
int i = NoOfStrings(s1);  // i = 2
```

I am just wondering if we can write a template meta program for this ! (since everything is known at compile time)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use the empty() member function of std::string like this e.g.:

```
    size_t stringArrSize(std::string *stringArray) {

       size_t num = 0;
       while (stringArray->empty() != true) {
           ++num;
           stringArray++;
       }
       return num;

    }
```