# final element of string array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I can't find the final element of a particular string array.
In this function I have an error in the execution when p reach the final element of the array.
Here is my code. Can anyone help me?

```
string mesi[] = { "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre" };
printMesi(mesi);
void printMesi(string v[])
{
    for (string* p = v; *p != string(0); p++)
        cout << (*p) << "\n";

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739384/how-to-find-number-of-elements-in-an-array-of-strings-in-c  please.

Comment: Only arrays constructed from string literals (`char f[] = "f";`) have any kind of termination marker.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, kindly accept it and close the question :)

Comment: I can't marked my question as resolved and closed it. Sorry. Can you help me also with it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. I'm passing the length of the array (which I have gotten from the main function)and then printing the data. In C++, when you pass an array as a parameter, you can't determine the size directly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printMesi(string v[], int length)
{
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    string mesi[] = { "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre" };
    printMesi (mesi, sizeof(mesi)/sizeof(mesi[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Code in action: http://ideone.com/YcWAOA

Answer (score -1):

This expresssion

```
string(0)
```

is already invalid and results in undefined behaviour.

The compiler considers this expression like

```
string( (const char * )0 )
```

but null pointer may not be used in this constructor.

The loop you wrote could work if you define one more element in the array - an empty string as for example

```
string mesi[] = 
{ 
    "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", 
    "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre", "" 
                                                                        ^^^
};

printMesi(mesi);
void printMesi(string v[])
{
    for (string* p = v; *p != ""; p++)
        cout << (*p) << "\n";
}
```

However first of all there is no sense to declare the array as an array of strings. It is an array of a fixed size with values that are supposed to be immutable.

So it is better to use string literals instead of objects of type std::string.

I would suggest to use `std::array` instead of the ordinary array. For example

```
#include <array>

//...

std::array<const char *, 12> mesi = 
{
    {
        "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", 
        "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre" 
    }
};


void printMesi( const std::array<const char *, 12> &mesi );
{
    for ( const char *m : mesi ) std::cout << m << "\n";
}

printMesi( mesi );
```

If your compiler does not support the class `std::array` then you can use an ordinary array declared the following way

```
const char * mesi[] = 
{ 
    "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", 
    "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre", 0 
};
```

and the function can look like

```
void printMesi( const char *mesi[])
{
    for ( const char *m = mesi; m != 0; m++ )
        std::cout << m << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @ShreyansSheth The class std::array is introduced in C++ 2011.

Comment: Yes that's what. This could lead to compatibility issues

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Please do not imagine your own compatibility issues.

Comment: Umm..that's a bit rude. And my college still uses C++03. Just like a lot of other places. The above code would not compile there. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth It is your personal problem. You can use with the same success the C++ 89. One more do not imagine your own compatibility issues. It is not your question.

Comment: http://ideone.com/hK9ENZ  There you go. Your code doesn't compile there whereas it runs fine on C++11. All I'm saying was that you should've mentioned c++11 in the answer. That's all :)

Comment: @ShreyansSheth I am repeating the third time: it is your personal problem. Now there is 2015 year in the world. After the C++ 2011 there was adopted C++ 2014 and sooner there will be adopted the C++ 2017. Of course you personally may use C++ 89. But again it is your personal problem.

Comment: There is no point arguing with you. Besides, looking at your reputation, I would always be the one on the wrong side. All i'm saying is that 'It's not my personal problem' but a lot of places still use old compilers. We have to be wary of that and for such an easy question, we can suggest something that works on every compiler. That was the motive. That is all